# Delete all waypoints from building in Supreme Commander 2

Tags: supreme-commander-2

In either Supreme Commander 2, or Supreme Commander: Forged Alliance, is there an easy to way to delete a buildings patrol route without having to go through each point one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a new rally point by right-clicking on the map (with the factory selected, of course, and without holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>). This will replace the patrol route. You can then start a fresh patrol route if you like.